# Which machine learning algorithm I have to use for sequence prediction?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, time-series

I have a dataset like below. I have datetime column as index, **type** is a column with sequence. For ex; R,C,D,D,D,R,R is a sequence.

```
start_time              type

2019-12-14 09:00:00     RCDDDRR 
2019-12-14 10:00:00     CCRD                
2019-12-14 11:00:00     DDRRCC  
2019-12-14 12:00:00     ?
```

I want to predict what would be the next sequence at time 12:00:00? which is the best algorithm to predict the next sequence?

I know that we can use Markov chain to predict the probable sequence. However, are there any other better algorithms?

Thanks

Comment: i think you are looking for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network

Answer (score 1):

you can use from knn,svm for prediction.but the first of all you have to change database and define feature for  training dataset for example

[image]

you can use from another method base on deep learning , I think this link can help you
https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Comment: Here Y is the predicting variable. How do we convert this categorical variable into numerical value? We can use LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder to convert this to numerical values. But there will be huge number of sequences given the size of the data set and we will end up having lots and lots of classes to predict.

Comment: you have to convert y with numerical using a function or manual. in the function, you using from a random function for the generated number

Comment: If you one hot encode, you can fall into the curse of dimensionality.  If you convert it to a number, the algorithm might learn the ordinal order (1 is less than 2 which is less than 3). maybe use a classifier that is able to handle categorical variables, such as lgbm or other types of trees.

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs have an edge over conventional feed-forward neural networks and RNN in many ways. This is because of their property of selectively remembering patterns for long durations of time.

LSTMs on the other hand, make small modifications to the information by multiplications and additions. With LSTMs, the information flows through a mechanism known as cell states. This way, LSTMs can selectively remember or forget things. The information at a particular cell state has three different dependencies.

Let’s take the example of predicting stock prices for a particular stock. The stock price of today will depend upon:

- The trend that the stock has been following in the previous days, maybe a downtrend or an uptrend.
- The price of the stock on the previous day, because many traders compare the stock’s previous day price before buying it.
- The factors that can affect the price of the stock for today. This can be a new company policy that is being criticized widely, or a drop in the company’s profit, or maybe an unexpected change in the senior leadership of the company.

These dependencies can be generalized to any problem as:

- The previous cell state (i.e., the information that was present in the memory after the previous time step).
- The previous hidden state (this is the same as the output of the previous cell).
- The input at the current time step (i.e., the new information that is being fed in at that moment).

Maybe this link and method could help you

https://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf
[https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/12/fundamentals-of-deep-learning-introduction-to-lstm/](http://%20%20[https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/12/fundamentals-of-deep-learning-introduction-to-lstm/][2])

Comment: Thanks for the reply Moeen. Here Y is the predicting variable. How do we convert this categorical variable into numerical value? We can use LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder to convert this to numerical values. But there will be huge number of sequences given the size of the data set and we will end up having lots and lots of classes to predict. How will you feed this to RNN. Could you please give me an example?